# Prove that there exists $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(\theta)| > |a_0|$ for $f(\theta) = a_0 + a_1e^{i\theta} + \dots + a_ne^{ni\theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n \geq 1$ and let $\{a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ be complex numbers such that $a_n \neq 0$. For $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, define

$$f(\theta) = a_0 + a_1e^{i\theta} + a_2e^{2i\theta} + \dots + a_ne^{ni\theta}$$

Prove that there exists $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(\theta)| > |a_0|$.

My attempt at a solution -

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $|f(\theta)| < |a_0|$ for all $\theta$. Then $f(\theta)$ is bounded and entire everywhere so by Liouville's Theorem it is constant. Contradiction.

What am I not seeing/overlooking here?

Comment: "Bounded"... on the real line only, which proves nothing. // Hint for a solution: Integrate $f$ on $(0,2\pi)$ and try to use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n$. Then $f(\theta)=P(e^{i\theta})$. Since $n\in\mathbb N$, $P$ is not constant and therefore, by the maximum modulus principle, the maximum of the restriction of $P$ to the closed unit disk is attainded at the boundary and only at the boundary. In particular $|a_0|=\bigl|P(0)\bigr|<\bigl|P(z)\bigr|$ for some $|z|=1$, and this means that$$(\exists\theta\in\mathbb{R}):|a_0|<\bigl|f(\theta)\bigr|.$$

Comment: ?? Let me suggest to check the case $P(z)=z+1$.

Comment: @Did I corrected my answer. Thanks.